# Converting Lat/Long coordinates to ESRI format

Tags: qgis, coordinates

Currently I have a CSV file which has Lat/Long coordinates which I got from the batch geocoding site, http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/#.VkWv97fNy70.

I believe these are obtained from Google maps. I would like to map these coordinates. However, when I try to use Layer>Add Delimited Text layer, and select my Long and Lat coordinates all I get is errors.

For reference the coordinates in my CSV file are as such.

> 51.494738 -9.720526

While when I upload my map into QGIS and zoom in to a region the coordinates which appear on the bottom of the screen are as such;

> 152930,309827

How do I go about either converting my coordinates in my CSV so they can be read in QGIS or can I change the coordinates of my Shapefile?

Comment: Why Esri in the title? Do you mean shapefile instead? It looks like your map is using Irish National Grid. Is that true?